# When exporting table in rich object tools to Fast Report, merging cells break down in Fast Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, richtextbox, fastreport

We need to overcome a problem about FastReport and we want to get support from you. We would like to mention about details of the problem as below: 
This problem is briefly related to entegration of RichEdit and FastReport. When a table is designed in the Rich tool and it is transferred to FastReport page, it is broken down and not showing properly in FastReport.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cinnf.png)
As shown below picture, merging of cells create a problem after table is transferred to FastReport page from Rich tool. And sometimes, borders of table may break down on the page.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I want to show it with picture, but stackover does not allow. Problem is that I design a table(with merging cells)  in rich edit, then transferring to Fast Report merging cells of table broke down in fast report page. I didn't find any solution on the Internet or related link.